# xcopy works from command prompt but fails in batch file using variable

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to run a batch file against a list of remote computers.

The batch file will check for a specific file, if the file is not found in the directory it should be copied there.

I am using the %%a variable for the PC names.

The xcopy command fails in the batch file with invalid drive specification.

If I take the xcopy command and replace the variable with the computer name and run from a command prompt it will copy the file over.

I am not sure why the xcopy command fails in the batch file when using %%a

PC.txt is my text file with the list of computers.

I am using the hostname and not the FQDN in the text file

```
    for /f %%a in (PCList.txt) do (
        If Exist "\\%%a\c$\Program Files\Folder\App.exe" (
            ECHO %%a App.exe exists
        ) ELSE (
           ECHO %%a App.exe Does Not Exist
           xcopy "C:\Folder\App.exe" "\\%%a\c$\Program Files\SubFolder\" /Q /R /Y
```

Comment: Is here a final ``)`` on that?

Comment: There should be at least two closing parentheses, @ChuckWalbourn! I would also would like to know based upon those leading spaces zimboy, is that code also nested within another parenthesized block?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you have one or two syntax errors. You opened a parenthesis in `... Folder\App.exe" (`and you haven't closed it since, the same thing with the `) ELSE (`. Also, sometimes the parenthesis inside a FOR can cause interference with the rest of the code. If you add the missing parenthesis does not resolve, try to fix the code to: `Folder\App.exe" ^(` which can help.

Try this:

```
for /f %%a in (PCList.txt) do (
        If Exist "\\%%a\c$\Program Files\Folder\App.exe" ECHO %%a App.exe exists
        ) ELSE (
           ECHO %%a App.exe Does Not Exist
           xcopy "C:\Folder\App.exe" "\\%%a\c$\Program Files\SubFolder\" /Q /R /Y )
```

Also, you can use the COPY only, maybe the problem is with the COPY. And using the parameter `if exist` to a entire .exe isn't the best idea, the user can just create a txt file and rename it as App.exe.

***Hope this helps,

K.***

Comment: I am sorry for my delay in responding but work related issues took precedence. I appreciate the comments and I tried all of the options and I am still not able to copy the file over, as I am still getting the error message invalid drive specification.

Comment: @zimboy ...It means that you are not using a valid drive letter, probably, so you just need to look at the paths...

Comment: I took another look at the paths and if I run the xcopy command from from a command prompt and replace the %%a with the computer name the xcopy command completes successfully.  But in the batch file with %%a the xcopy commands errors out. But it does work to check for the file existence

Comment: @zimboy Try to use `echo %%a` and `echo (the path, copy & paste)` like `echo \\%%a\c$\Program Files\SubFolder\`